# How to read log files in python in django

Tags: python, django, linux

I am trying to read the log files or any other file and display in web browser using django and python

I used this code

```
 data_file = open('/var/log/samba', 'r') # note -- 'r' not r
 data = data_file.readlines()       # returns a list of lines
```

I get this error

```
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/log/samba'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to open a directory. Don't do that. Open a file instead.

Comment: oh sorry for that , i tried `vim samba` and it got opened , so i thougt it was a file. But now i am getting permission issue as all files are rw by root only. i can't make all log files 777. whats the solution for this

Comment: I am new to django so i don't know how open as root. Any examples?

Comment: You need to run Django as root. This is why no one writes sysadmin tools in Django.